# What is the difference between pointer,reference,identifier,variable

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between them in python ? Is variable also an object but don't have value ?

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers. Do you mean C/C++?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I heard that Python reference is similar to C pointer, can you explain ?

Comment: As far as I know, I'm not aware of this concept in Python. With C pointers you can do pointer arithmetic and address memory directly, but that isn't available in Python (sort of, look at `array` module). You can interface C with `ctypes` or `cffi` but that is essentially for bridging C and Python.

Answer (score 1):

Hello may be this is some difference between this python terms:

- Reference variable:
  Python program accesses data values through references. A reference is a name that refers to the specific location in memory of a value (object). References take the form of variables, attributes, and items. In Python, a variable or other reference has no intrinsic type.
- Pointer:
  Well, python does not have pointers, but the objects are passed to functions by reference (and so in java, another language without pointers). This mechanism is very similar to passing pointers by value in C.
- Identifier:
  A Python identifier is a name used to identify a variable, function, class, module or other object. An identifier starts with a letter A to Z or a to z or an underscore (_) followed by zero or more letters, underscores and digits (0 to 9).
- Variable:
  A Python variable is a reserved memory location to store values. In other words, a variable in a python program gives data to the computer for processing. Every value in Python has a datatype. Different data types in Python are Numbers, List, Tuple, Strings, Dictionary, etc